# Python \n gives two spaces in between output and \t gives one

Tags: python

I do not understand why when inputing a space between the code with \t gives one space of line between the 'green' and 'Some things I learned so far:' output. When I use \n it gives two spaces inbetween. Shouldn't the space be the same for either \t and \n? I know that \t does tab and \n is new line. but I do not understand how \n does two spaces inbetween
Code is:

```
fav_num = {
    'rachel':'blue',
    'hannah':'green',
}
print(fav_num['rachel'])
print(fav_num['hannah'])
#6-3
coding_glossary = {
    'list':'mutable type where you can store info',
    'tuple':'immutable type similar to list',
    'string':'simple line of code'
}
print('\t')
print('Some things I learned so far: \n')
print('What a list is:')
print(coding_glossary['list'])
```

Output is :

```
blue
green

Some things I learned so far: 

What a list is:
mutable type where you can store info

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: ‘print()’ adds it’s own new line on the end of what you ask it to print.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

python's [built-in print function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) has '\n' as end character implicitly.

> `print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)`:
>
> Print objects to the text stream file, separated by sep and **followed by end**. sep, end, file and flush, if present, must be given as keyword arguments

So, every time you run `print()` there is a '`\n`' character that gets printed implicitly unless you override the behavior by passing `end=` to it. (like `end=''` for instance)

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be equivalently written:

```
#
print()
print(‘Some things I learned so far:’)
print()
#
```

Answer (score 1):

By default print put a new line at the end, to modify this behavior you can set the end parameter with end=""

Example:

```
print("this will use 2 lines \n")
print("this will use 1 line")
print("this will use 1 line \n", end="")
```

Answer (score 1):

print by default goes to the next line. try

```
print(" ",end = "")
```

so you can see '\t' more clearly.

Also, tab jumps to the next block. A block is usually 4 spaces.
Try this and notice where the . is:

```
print("\t", end=".\n")
print("A\t", end=".\n")
print("ABC\t", end=".\n")
print("ABCD\t", end=".\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

The statement `print('\t')` is printing a tab, then returning to the next line, as the default print function automatically adds a newline. So you can't see the tab, but it is there. When you add \n to the end of the string you print, it adds a line return in addition to the default line return.

To remove the default line return, specify the 'end' parameter of the print function:

`print('abcd\n', end='')`

This will only include one line return.

Answer (score 0):

Since print() does give an `'\n'` string at the end of each output the command `print('\n')` gives the commandline string `'\t\n'`.

For more details please see the following well documented post [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-newline-or-space)

Answer (score 0):

`"\n"` character is a newline character and when you print `"\n"` it sets the cursor to a new line. `print` always sets a new line in the end by default. But you can change that behavior by setting the value of `end` argument to an empty string.

```
print("hello", end="")
```

`"\t"` is a `tab` character

```
for i in range(20):
    print("current number is\t", I)

# current number is    0
# current number is    1
# current number is    2
# current number is    3
# current number is    4
# current number is    5
# current number is    6
# current number is    7
# current number is    8
# current number is    9
# current number is    10
# current number is    11
# current number is    12
# current number is    13
# current number is    14
# current number is    15
# current number is    16
# current number is    17
# current number is    18
# current number is    19
```

[Find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) more magic characters which can be useful in your programs